# Where to store ID tokens and which OAuth2 flow to use in a monolithic server-side rendered web app?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm having trouble understanding how do I store ID tokens in a regular server-side rendered web app (for example, JSP/Servlet-based). After reading some OAuth2/OIDC guides and documentation, it seems like most of these sources assume the the client and the resource server (in OAuth2 terminology) are different applications. A really clear use case which is often described is if you have a Singe Page App (the client) and you want it to access some APIs (the resource server) on behalf of a user (the resource owner). I do understand that a classic server-side rendered web app can also be the client, but usually it is assumed that it is still separate from the resource server and it does requests to some remote APIs on behalf of a user (same as an SPA would).

My use case, on the other hand, is that I have a monolithic web app which servers as both the client and the resource server, but I just don't want to implement authentication myself (I would like to delegate authentication to an external OIDC authorization server). According to the sources I've read, I am supposed to use Authorization Code flow in the above case, which means that after successful authentication my backend will exchange the received authorization code for an ID token. But where do I store it then? Am I supposed to just create a good old session and set a cookie after that? This is certainly doable, but this defeats the purpose of using ID tokens which are self-contained JWTs. Or should I assume that ID tokens can completely substitute session/cookie combo only if they are stored on the client-side (mobile app or SPA)? Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an ID token from an OIDC Provider (the Authorization Server in OIDC is called the OIDC Provider - OP), which means that you only want to authenticate the user. It's important to understand that separation - an OIDC flow is used to authenticate a user, not to perform session management (OIDC does provide features for session management, but I don't think it's what you're after). You get the ID token from OP to learn who the user is. That token will usually be short-lived. You can use that token to either identify the user in your database or create an account for them (if that's needed), and then, create a session. As you have a good ol'fashioned website, then go with a cookie-based session.

> This is certainly doable, but this defeats the purpose of using ID tokens which are self-contained JWTs

No, it doesn't ;) As I mentioned, ID tokens are not a mechanism for session management. They just carry information about the authenticated user. As such, you don't have to persist them anywhere, you just need to get the information from an ID token.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your OAuth/OIDC question. The ID token isn't a result of the grant type (save the client credentials flow).

Have you read this:
https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html

I recommend reading the whole page, but this section seems especially relevant: Session Management Implementation.

> The session management implementation defines the exchange mechanism that will be used between the user and the web application to share and continuously exchange the session ID. There are multiple mechanisms available in HTTP to maintain session state within web applications, such as cookies (standard HTTP header), URL parameters (URL rewriting – RFC2396), URL arguments on GET requests, body arguments on POST requests, such as hidden form fields (HTML forms), or proprietary HTTP headers.

And

> The preferred session ID exchange mechanism should allow defining advanced token properties, such as the token expiration date and time, or granular usage constraints. This is one of the reasons why cookies (RFCs 2109 & 2965 & 6265) are one of the most extensively used session ID exchange mechanisms, offering advanced capabilities not available in other methods.

So, yes, use a cookie. A cookie is sort of the defacto standard.

Comment: Regarding your first comment: as far as I understand, any OAuth2 flow results in a Access and ID token (otherwise what's the point).

Comment: So does your answer mean that self-contained JWT ID tokens can replace cookies/session only if we these tokens are managed client-side?

Comment: Well, technically the ID token comes from OIDC not from OAuth. And the client credentials flow doesn't typically return an ID token since it's the client acting on it's own behalf, i.e., not a user.

Comment: Yes the token should be passed with every request from the user to client.